# Why should every metric space be open?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am reading a book called: Introduction to Topology (Mendelson) and there the following statement has been made.

**Theorem 6.4:**
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.
Then $X$ is open.

The question instantly arises: Why would $([0,1], d)$, where $d$ is the euclidean distance not be a metric space?

So I have to take into account, that the book changed the definition of open:

Quote:

> A subset $O$ of a metric space is said to be open if $O$ is a
> neighbourhood of each of its points.

But surely, any good definition of "Openness" would boil down to the standard definition for the case above?

Am I missing something?

Comment: If $(X,\mathcal T)$ is a topological space then $X$ is always open and closed... $([0,1],d)$ is obviously a metric space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The set $[0,1]$ **is** an open subset of $[0,1]$ with respect to the Euclidean metric.

It is true that $[0,1]$ is not an open subset of $\Bbb R$, but that's not relevant here.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the crux here. Thanks for Clarification 